# Docker run with arguments that take one and two hypens

Tags: docker

Learning docker so I have some dumb questions

1. Came across the below command , why is that some arguments have only one hyphen (-) while others have two hypens (--). One of them is not a argument? Like interactive terminal is -it , while remove container is with --rm ?

   docker run -it --rm --entrypoint sh debug/ubuntu
2. What does --rm do in the above command. rm is to remove the container so why are they passing it when running the container?

Comment: `docker run -h` would tell you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52614972/13217070)

> This is a standard Unix/Linux syntax, not specific to docker. One dash
> is used for single letter flags. Two dashes for an option that is more
> than one letter. You can merge together multiple single letter options
> that don't take arguments, e.g. -i and -t can be merged into -it. You
> can run docker --help to see all the options, some of which have both
> a long and short format.

2. The --rm means that the container will be removed automatically after it is stopped. Without --rm, it can be found "dangling" with `docker container ls --all`